# How to make bash prompt start at new line in vs code?

Tags: c, string, bash, visual-studio-code, scanf

I am currently using ubuntu 21.04. I was running a C code on my Visual Studio Code but my bash prompt is starting from the end of my output. I want to start bash prompt from new line.

CODE:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int i=0;
    char str1[20],str2[20];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s",str1);
    while (str1[i]!='\0')
    {
        str2[i]=str1[i];
        i++;
    }
    printf("The copy of string is: %s",str2);
}
```

[OUTPUT:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9elrq.png)

Comment: You probably want a trailing new line: `"The copy of string is: %s\n"`.

Comment: I know that but by this I have to change my each and every code. I windows bash prompt used to start automatically from new line but in ubuntu it is not working.

Comment: Well, your program is unsafe anyway, so you would have to touch it in any case. Of course you could configure your prompt, so that it starts with a newline everytime, but then you get an empty line after each "well behaved" program, which does terminate its output with a newline. Perhaps you are better off fixing your own programs.

Answer (score 1):

Your source code has an error, the result string is not NULL terminated. You must copy the terminated '\0' in `str2`. A possible fix is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int i=0;
    char str1[20],str2[20];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s",str1);
    do
    {
        str2[i]=str1[i];
    } while (str1[i++]!='\0');
    printf("The copy of string is: %s",str2);
}
```

BUT the latter is still unsecure: check the maximum value for `i` to avoid an overflow  in `str2`.

Then, the way it works under Ubuntu is consistent: if you don't have a terminating newline in the string, the newline will no be displayed. Hence, the following prompt from the shell is displayed at the last position of the cursor.
If you want an new line in the resulting string, either you add it in the `printf()` format or you get it in the source string with a `fgets()` instead of a `scanf()` to get the return typed by the operator into `str1` as explained in the manual:

> fgets()  reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an EOF
> or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.  A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the  last  character  in  the
> buffer.

Here is an usage example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int i=0;
    char str1[20],str2[20];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets(str1, sizeof(str1), stdin);
    do
    {
        str2[i]=str1[i];
    } while (str1[i++]!='\0');
    printf("The copy of string is: %s",str2);
}
```

Example:

```
$ gcc scan.c -o scan
$ ./scan
Enter a string: qwerty
The copy of string is: qwerty
$
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me . It did worked but why it is happening even with a simple hello world program? 
I want my bash prompt to start from new line.